# Validation Rule: NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, master-data-services

My users would like to enter a value in the NAME attribute of an entity in SQL Server Master Data Services.  The valid values must contain zero to six characters.  NULL is a valid value.

I have written a validation rule with a action containing a regex to ensure that the value is six or less characters (`Name must contain the pattern ^.{0,6}$`), but the NULL values get flagged with a "Validation Failed" status.  I would like the NULL values to pass the validation test.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for your time.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show the actual code you are trying to amend.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question on another site.  I tested it, and it works.
Here it is:

Conditions:

`If
    MyAttribute contains the pattern .*`

Actions:

`Then
   MyAttribute must contain the pattern ^.{0,6}$`

Thanks

Comment: i am 100% sure there is nowhere where this will compile. This is not an answer, but then again, the question is also very very vague

Comment: @GuidoG: You are correct.  It will not compile. The MDS validation rules are configured via a drag-and-drop interface.  I cannot post the actual code here unless I post a screenshot.  I chose instead to represent the working configuration with pseudo-code.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "OR Name IS NULL" to the validation rule.

Comment: Thanks, Davide. My version does not offer that option.

Comment: This is for a SQL query